# How to count occurrance of values ranging 0.5 to 2 in a particular column of a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am a beginner in programming and I am trying to count all those values ranging from 0.5 to 2 in a column of a data frame using for loop stating entire range of the column and if-else condition. I need the % of those values out of all to get factor of 2 in pandas

Comment: Please add some data sample data and sample code on what you have tried https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @spandana, can you provide any little example. That would help us a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop and and a if-else condition is not a good practice.
You should rather use np.where which faster :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Assuming you have a df like this :
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

# You can check if values from column A is in range
df['is_in_range'] = np.where((df.A >= 0.5) & (df.A < 2), 'in_range', 'not_in_range')
print(df)

# Then you get the percentage of value in range and values not in range
percentage_value_in_range = df.is_in_range.value_counts(normalize=True)
print(percentage_value_in_range)
```